# c#+ sqlite, error : connection was closed statement was terminated

Tags: c#, sqlite

sqlite how close connectioin database

```
            try
            {
                Global.sqliteConnection.Close();
                Global.sqliteReader.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
```

[image]

error : connection was closed statement was terminated

Comment: don't you have to close the `Reader` before the `Connection` ?

Comment: Best way is put a using statement on the Connection.  Then when you exit the using statement it will automatically dispose the connection which will also close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example

```
string cs = @"URI=file:C:\somefile.db";

using(con = new SQLiteConnection(cs)) {
    con.Open();
    string stm = "SELECT * FROM tTable";
    using(cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con)) {
        using(SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                // Write the first one
                Console.WriteLine($"{rdr.GetInt32(0)}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By using the `using` keyword, we assure that all cleanup functions occur (not only the close one).

By using the `using` keyword, we assure that we cleanup the resources with the correct order. In your case, you are first closing the connection, and then the reader. In the example above, the exact opposite is happening.

You should also create a new connection each time you execute a query. No worries, there is not impact on performance, it's the way it's supposed to be (for more information, check connection pooling).

Stop using the Global connection variable, and just use the `new` Keyword